# Fragments, dealing with async configuration for onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynchronous, initialization

I have a Fragment in an Activity. When the Activity gets created, it triggers an asynchroneous load of the application state from a file. When this finishes, the Activity starts creating some paged Fragments, depending on the configuration state.

The problem is that when the OS kills the app, so that `onCreate(bundle)` has a stored state in the `bundle` because the OS took care of storing it prior to killing the app, the Fragments are also recreated immediately, but the application state is still getting read from the file, so they don't have access to the data they should be showing, which they need in their `onCreateView()`. This is because this time the Fragments are created by the OS, and not by the callback of the AsyncTask in the Activity's callback.

I'm hesitant towards making `onCreateView()` block/wait for the async result (even if it is avaliable in a fraction of second), so I'm thinking about moving the code which depends on the application state out of the Fragment's `onCreateView()`, and have some callback create it when the data is avaliable.

Ideally I'd work with deferreds/promises/futures, where I can "subscribe" to the async load result in the `onCreateView()` , but i'm too new to Java in order to know how to do this. I don't know which libraries exists or are suited for this.

Which suggestions do you have for me so I can deal in the best possible way with this issue?

Kind regards.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to check is the data is present when the fragments' onCreateView() method is called, and if it isn't, do nothing? You could then recreate the fragments from scratch as you had done originally.

Comment: No, not really. Since the restructuring/refactoring in the App is going to take some work, I'd rather get some feedback from SE prior to beginning with it. Or maybe I'm procrastinating? ;-)

Comment: Android's lifecycle is very poorly designed. The strategy that I find best for handling onCreate/onDestroy information access issues is by resetting the state of the program to some kind of default from which you can then reconstruct everything. In your case, this would mean recreating all fragments from scratch on every onCreate call. Not relying on the activity's bundle will bring better stability to the app.

Comment: @ReedB I'm not really convinced of that approach as I don't really understand how Android is using these bundles, and it may be the case that relying on them would be a smart(er) thing to do.
I'm also not that convinced of using a variable like "m_bIsInitialized", because there is this ambiguous moment where m_bIsInitialized is set to true and the fragment-set-up-function may have already been skipped. This is very improbable, but it doesn't feel right. I believe that the right way to deal with this would be to use deferreds. Or some other callback-based system.

Comment: The problem is much harder than anticipated. :( It looks like I will need to use empty placeholder-Fragments and swap them out as the data comes in...

Comment: @ReedB about what you say with "reconstruct everything", how can I prevent that automatic re-creation of the fragments?